# Azure Media Services Video not playing HTML5 Player

Tags: angularjs, html5-video, azure-media-services

Spent a few hours today trying to figure this out, hoping someone can enlighten me. I have a video hosted in Azure Media Services that I am calling a Web Service to get (using WebApi and Angular). The issue I am running into is that the video is not actually playing. Here is the View code in Angular I am using

```
    <video id="{{video.RowKey }}" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered embed-responsive-item" controls data-setup='{"logo": { "enabled": false }, "techOrder": ["azureHtml5JS", "flashSS", "silverlightSS", "html5"], "nativeControlsForTouch": false}'>
            <source src="{{vm.trustSrc(video.BlobUri)}}" type="application/dash+xml" />
            <p class="amp-no-js">
                To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video
            </p>
        </video>
```

And for completeness, this is what vm.trustSrc does

```
 vm.trustSrc = function (src) {
        return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
    }
```

The Html rendered looks like this

```
<video id="a273bf71-4b1f-439a-8f98-31d112511d8f" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered embed-responsive-item" controls="" data-setup="{&quot;logo&quot;: { &quot;enabled&quot;: false }, &quot;techOrder&quot;: [&quot;azureHtml5JS&quot;, &quot;flashSS&quot;, &quot;silverlightSS&quot;, &quot;html5&quot;], &quot;nativeControlsForTouch&quot;: false}">
            <source src="https://testams.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/6236bb64-cda4-4a05-960c-ae957729cf61/testvideo.ism/manifest(format=mpd-time-csf)" type="application/dash+xml">
            <p class="amp-no-js">
                To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video
            </p>
        </video>
```

I have tried a few different types (including application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml) and none of them play the video. I know this works but in my situation I cannot get it to work. I have looked through every tutorial and sample code I have came across and nothing seems to get me where I want. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked into https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/samples.html? Are you playing protected or not protected content?
It doesn't seems that you need source tag use src attribute in video tag instead.

Comment: @GeorgeTrifonov I have tried all the options there and none of them are working. I have tried both static and programmatic. I am accessing the video from https, so the video has to have that endpoint.

Comment: Are you actually able to download manifest or play it in azure portal? Link to a sample video you provided doesn't seems to be working. You need to create on-demand streaming locator and use it as source https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-deliver-streaming-content/.

Comment: I am doing that. I can get it to work fine using Dash, but not the Azure Player

Comment: I would suggest following steps for diagnostic: - check if you can download manifest using locator uri -check if you can playback in azure portal - use https://ampdemo.azureedge.net/ player and paste uri to see if you can playback it there by selecting appropriate options.